# Generate SVG code for usage in HTML file

Tags: html, svg, inkscape

I'm using the SVG-tag in a HTML file to create some graphics for a video player. Now I wanted to use Inkscape in order to create the svg code and then take the generated code and use it within my svg tag.

That approach seemed to work pretty fine at first. I designed a pause button and for the "d"-attribute inkscape generated the code:

```
M 12.5 10 L 12.5 30 L 17.5 30 L 17.5 10 L 12.5 10 z M 22.5 10 L 22.5 30 L 27.5 30 L 27.5 10 L 22.5 10 z
```

which works quite well in HTML. However, for the speaker symbol Inkscape generated this:

```
m8.0312,1028.4,0,8,6,0,6,6,0-20-6,6z
```

which doesn't work. Seeing, that there are more complex elements needed (compared to those straight lines), is there a way to directly convert those two?

Here are the two version embedded in a HTML file:

```html
<svg width="40px" height="40px">
  <path d="M 12.5 10 L 12.5 30 L 17.5 30 L 17.5 10 L 12.5 10 z M 22.5 10 L 22.5 30 L 27.5 30 L 27.5 10 L 22.5 10 z" fill="black" />
  
  <path d="m 8.03125,1028.3622 0,8 6,0 6,6 0,-20 -6,6 z" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

Greetings,
timo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<svg width="40px" height="40px">
  <path d="m 8.03125,15 0,8 6,0 6,6 0,-20 -6,6 z" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

Your problem is the 1028.3622.  Resize your Inkscape (Ctrl+Shift+D) page to be 40 px wide by 40 px high.  Put your image inside page and you should have no problem.

I've removed your pause button and tweaked relative y of play button.

Comment: Oh god, I'm an idiot. I had the speaker path grouped with some others and for some weird reason Inkscape gave this group a huge vertical translate that was then "erased" by that huge number in the actual path.

I wonder why Inkscape behaved like that, but thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: You'll get used to the idiosyncrasies of Inkscape.